# Axios: How to attach X-XSRF-TOKEN header manually?

Tags: node.js, laravel, vue.js, axios, server-side-rendering

I'm developing an SSR app with Vue. The API is made using Laravel framework and i'm using axios to send requests to the API.

I have to make a POST request on server-side to fetch it's response and render it on initial page load. To fetch the CSRF token for the POST request, the Laravel API provides an endpoint that sends the CSRF response as **JSON** (instead of a cookie because cookies cannot be used on server-side).

I'm attaching the csrf token in the following way:

```
this._vm.$api.post('/api/ssr-csrf-token').then(response => {
    console.log("Token: ", response.data.token); // This shows that csrf is fetched correctly
    
    let config = {
        headers: {
          'X-XSRF-TOKEN': response.data.token
        }
    };

    this._vm.$api.post('/api/product/categories', { some: "thing"}, config).then(response => {
        console.log("Categories: ", response.data.data);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    })
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
})
```

But sending the request this way still gives the **"CSRF Token Mismatch"** error. Even though the token is attached to the request.

When I use Postman to fetch the results on categories endpoint, everything works fine and I get the response as should. But making a request from my SSR project I'm not receiving the response.

What do I need to do to get the response? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can attach the token to axios.defaults.headers.common.

next time, when you make a call, it auto sets your token to the header.

```
this._vm.$api.post('/api/ssr-csrf-token').then(response => {
    console.log("Token: ", response.data.token); // This shows that csrf is fetched correctly

    // set token to your header
  axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] =
      'Bearer ' + response.data.response.access_token;

    this._vm.$api.post('/api/product/categories', { some: "thing"}).then(response => {
        console.log("Categories: ", response.data.data);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    })
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
})
```

Now you don't have to include the config variable in your request. it auto sets to the header on your all calls.

Comment: Thank you or your reply. But this isn't a bearer token but a CSRF/XSRF token and needs to be attached as X-XSRF-TOKEN to the request. 

Also as I pointed attaching the token using Postman gives the response correctly. But attaching it from Axios gives error.
The error still persists using the method in your reply.